# How do I immediately retrieve a row that has just been written to the database

Tags: sql, database

When I click a button, I have it so that a row is inserted into the database, and that works. However, I need to also retrieve that same row to display it on the page. Here is what I have:

```
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Store (FirstName) Values ('" + txtFirstName.Text + "')";
comm.CommandText = "Select FirstName from Store";
```

Since the second line of code happens after the first line, shouldn't it show the new entry? Currently only previous entries are shown for the database. How do I get the new one to show up?

Comment: You don't seem to be executing the queries between the assignments.

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: Couple things -- watch out for sql injection, use paramaterized queries.  Looks like SQL Server?  Assuming you have have an `identity` as a primary key, use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to get  your most recent entry...

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In many RDBMS systems, you can use the `OUTPUT` clause to output data that's just been inserted, deleted, updated.

So in your case, you could use

```
INSERT INTO Store (FirstName) 
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, Inserted.FirstName
VALUES(@FirstName);
```

To output the auto-generated `ID` (assuming it's some sort of an auto-increment column - `IDENTITY` in SQL Server) and the `FirstName` you've just inserted.